# Cannot bind Map to Object in Spring Configuration Properties from YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, maps, configurationproperties

I have the following configuration in my Spring boot's application.yml file:

```
project:
 country-properties:
   france:
     capital: paris
     population: 60
```

And I have the the properties class : CountryProperties :

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="project.country-properties") 
public class CountryProperties {
      private Map<String, CountryData> countryProperties;

      @Getter
      @Setter
      public static class CountryData {
          private String capital; 
          private Integer population; 
      }
```

However my CountryProperties is always null, and it's because of a failed mapping with the CountryData object.
Any ideas what is wrong with what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You have the annotation `@ConstructorBinding`. This annotation tells Spring to look for a constructor in your class that has parameters corresponding to your configuration properties, and then will bind the properties.

What you are missing is:

```
public CountryProperties(Map<String, CountryData> countryProperties) {
    this.countryProperties = countryProperties;
}
```

Update:

After inspecting your code again, it looks like you aren't mapping the configuration correctly to the instance field. Please update your `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="project.country-properties")` to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="project")`.

Also replace the `@ConstructorBinding` with `@Configuration`.

Comment: It dosn't solve the issue, I think since I have the @AllArgsConstructor then the constructor already exists :x

Comment: Looks like your not mapping the data right to the instance field. Please replace ```@ConstructorBinding``` with ```@Configuration``` and update your prefix to ```@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "project")```

Comment: For me map is not null but empty. @Sy3d